# Firebase data structure / AngularJs data retrieving

Tags: firebase

i would like to know if : 
1 - My data structure is ok (relational, id, ...)
2 - In angular, How can i retrieve a list of "logements" for an account ID ?
 I really don't understand something here . Can you help me please ?

That's how i try to retrieve this list and stock it in $scope.items

```js
    var ref_logement = firebase.database().ref('logements');
         var ref_accounts = firebase.database().ref('accounts');
         var AccountLogement = ref_accounts.child(accountId).child('logements');
         AccountLogement.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
       console.log(snapshot.val());
       ref_logement.child(snapshot.key).on("value", function(snapshot2) {
               $scope.isLoaded = false;
               $scope.items = snapshot2.val();
console.log(snapshot2.val());
            });
         });
```

And this is what i have in the console
 **{adresse: "5, Yaroslavl', Yaroslavskaya oblast', Russie, 150042", disponibilite: "non", lat: 57.68679710000001, lng: 39.80589740000005, nom: "Bb"}


{adresse: "2 rue ", disponibilité: "non", lat: 12, lng: 1, nom: "oui oui"}**
2 lines ! And $scope.items is null ... How can i list every "logements" for each "account" (user) please ?

Thank you in advance

MydataBase
----- **accounts**
---------- Unique ID
--------------- infos1
--------------- infos2
--------------- geofire
--------------------- Unique ID from geofire table : true
--------------------- Unique ID from geofire table : true
--------------- logements
--------------------- Unique ID from logements table : true
--------------------- Unique ID from logements table : true
--------------- dateCreated
--------------- dateCreated
----- **geofire**
---------- Unique ID
--------------- g
--------------- l
--------------------- lat
--------------------- lng
----- **logements**
---------- Unique ID
--------------- adresse
--------------- nom
--------------- lat
--------------- long
[image: Firebase data structure]

Comment: Please add your data as text, not an image. This makes it searchable and it can be used in a possible answer. Also what have you tried so far for retrieving the data?

Comment: Hi André, i try to explain better my problem. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: It looks pretty normal to me. You need to state whether or not this works. If it already works then you should close the question because everyone will have a different opinion on how to structure your data.

Comment: `{adresse: "5, Yaroslavl', Yaroslavskaya oblast', Russie, 150042", disponibilite: "non", lat: 57.68679710000001, lng: 39.80589740000005, nom: "Bb"}
{adresse: "2 rue ", disponibilité: "non", lat: 12, lng: 1, nom: "oui oui"}` This is the result in the console

Comment: How can i have a full array with this 2 lines ? What am i missing please ? I really don't know if it is the good technique

Answer (score 0):

this is how i retrieve my data ! Thank you for all

```js
   var ref_logement = firebase.database().ref('logements');
     var ref_accounts = firebase.database().ref('accounts');
    ref_logement.orderByChild('id_account').equalTo(accountId).once("value", function(snapshot)
     {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
 $scope.items = snapshot.val();
    });
```